# Can anyone tell me why this program go to infinite times?

Tags: c

```
#include< stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int n,a=0,i=1,b=11;

        while(i<=2)
        {

                while(i>0)
                {
                        a=a+b;
                        i--;
                }
                printf("%d",a);
                i++;
        }
}
```

but if i make a little change i will get the output..
what is the difference between both the code??

```
#include< stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int n,a=0,i=1,b=11;

        while(i<=2)
        {
                n=i;

                while(n>0)
                {
                        a=a+b;
                        n--;
                }   
                printf("%d\n",a);
                i++;
        }
}
```

output-
11
33

Comment: If you print out the value of `i` in your first outer and inner loops, you should figure it out, it may be that your `i` never becomes > 2 when you run the conditional statements in your while() loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (i <= 2)
{
    while (i > 0)
    {
        a = a + b;
        i--;    <- out the inner while loop when i = 0
    }
    printf("%d", a);
    i++;        <- at here, the i==0 each time, so infinity loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your nested loop always restores the value of i to 0, 
And 0 <= 2 is always true, thus it keeps on going.
Initially the value of i is 1, the first loop starts by checking i<=2 , which is true for i=1, then the second loop checks i>0, which is also true, then the second loop decreases the value of i to 0 by i--;
This time the test condition for the nested loop fails and the inner loop exits, back in the first loop, the condition is satisfied as i=0 is<= 2 thus i is incremented, now i = 1.
This keeps on going forever.
In the second code, you're copying the current value of i to n, thus, initially i = 1;
Condition for first loop satisfied, then you set n = i,
And check n >0 which is true as n = i = 1
In this loop you are decrementing n and n becomes 0, thus the loop quits, and the outer loop increments i, i now being 2 allows the outer loop to run and then again n = i = 2,
The inner loop runs twice and then exits and i is incremented to 3 failing the outer loop condition and hence quitting the loop. And you get the result.

Comment: It's ok, looks like you're starting your programming journey. If the answer solved your query, can you mark it?

Comment: Oh, how long have you been programming?

Comment: from the past 14 days

Comment: That's what I was saying.. you've started learning programming.

Comment: Hey does the answer solved your query? If yes please mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code your 
     `While(i<=2)` never ends because you add `1` to `i` with `i++` and then you subtract `1` from `i` with `i--` and you never get `i=3` to end the while loop.